# I want to show the menu header layout in selected pages in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, menu

I have made a **menu.html.erb page in layout** folder
i am using

```
<body>
<%=render 'layouts/menus'%>
<%= yield %>
<%=render 'layouts/footers'%>
</body>
```

in application.html.rb
my problem is that **this menu and footer applies to all the pages** that i don't  want.

I **want some pages that does not have these menu and footer**

Any help please???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just another clever way to do this.

You could put at the top your Controller a before_filter :

```
before_filter :have_sidebar except: [:show, :index]
#                                      ^ This is an example, but choose whatever views you do not want it to appear in.

 # Add this to your controller methods.
def have_sidebar
  @have_sidebar = true
end
```

Then in your application.html.erb, write this :

```
<body>
<%=render 'layouts/menus' if @have_sidebar %>
<%= yield %>
<%=render 'layouts/footers' if @have_sidebar %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want those pages without the menu/footer to use the application layout, then you can do:

```
<body>
<%=render 'layouts/menus' if @show_menu %>
<%= yield %>
<%=render 'layouts/footers' if @show_footer%>
</body>
```

where @show_menu and @show_footer can be defined elsewhere.

Or, if you don't want to use the application layout, you can change it, for example:

```
render :view, :layout => "another layout"
render :view, :layout => false # don't use any layout
```

Comment: I done but if i use it in one view it hides menu from all the views under that controller...